# Identification of points in Adjunction space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X\coprod Y / \sim$  be the adjunction space.Show that $\sim$ identifies each point of $x\in X$ with all the points in $f^{-1}(x)\subseteq A$.

Where $f:A\rightarrow Y$ is the attaching map.

How do I even begin attempting this? May I have some help please?

Comment: I would say this is the definition of an adjunction space.  What is your definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $A \subseteq X$, then $a \sim f(a)$ by definition and if $a' \in f^{-1}[\{f(a)\}]$ then $f(a')=f(a)$ and also by definition $a' \sim f(a')$, so transitivity of $\sim$ forces $A \sim a'$, so all points of $f^{-1}[\{f(a)\}]$ are identified for every $a \in A$.

So points in $A$ with the same image under $f$ are identified, which is another way of putting your statement.